# Using Mathematica to find an alternative continued fraction for $\zeta(5)$

Tags: polynomials, number-theory, searching, experimental-mathematics, continued-fractions

Given the *Riemann zeta function* $\zeta(n)$.

> **I.** $x=\zeta(3)$

Using *[Euler's continued fraction formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_continued_fraction#Euler.27s_continued_fraction_formula)*, we can form $\zeta(3)$'s cfrac as,

$$Ax+B = \cfrac{1}{v_1 - \cfrac{1^6}{v_2 - \cfrac{2^6}{v_3 - \cfrac{3^6}{v_4 -\ddots}}}}\tag1$$

A solution to $(1)$ is $A,B = 1,0,$ where,

$$v_n := (n-1)^3+n^3 = (2n - 1)(n^2 - n + 1)$$

starting with $n=1$. However, Apéry also found $A,B = \tfrac{1}{6},0,$ and,

$$v_n := 34n^3 - 51n^2 + 27n - 5 = (2n - 1)(17n^2 - 17n + 5)$$

and proved that the accelerated rate of convergence was such that $x=\zeta(3)$ could not be rational.

> **II.** $x=\zeta(5)$

$$Ax^2+Bx+C = \cfrac{1}{v_1 - \cfrac{1^{10}}{v_2 - \cfrac{2^{10}}{v_3 - \cfrac{3^{10}}{v_4 -\ddots}}}}\tag2$$

A solution to $(2)$ is $A,B,C=0,1,0,$ where,

$$v_n := (n-1)^5+n^5 = (2 n-1) (n^4-2 n^3+4 n^2-3 n+1)
$$

> **Question:** For $\zeta(5)$, what would be an efficient *Mathematica* code to find an ***alternative*** rational $A,B,C,$ and ***quintic*** polynomial $v_n$  with integer coefficients?

Comment: Is there any special reason for the quadratic in the expression for $\zeta(5)$?

Comment: @J.M. I've tried a crude and limited search with $A=0$, but there was no hit. So perhaps I was missing another term. (Or maybe my bounds for the quintic's coefficients were too small.)

Answer (score 2):

My guess would be to search first for polynomials of shape $$(2n-1)(a(n^2-n)^2+b(n^2-n)+c),$$ as it might be a good assumption from [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/322965/representations-of-zeta3-as-continued-fractions-involving-cubic-polynomials) that the zeros are symmetric w.r.t. $n=\frac12$. But of course that is pure speculation. I have done some experiments with GP Pari for positive odd $a,b,c$ but not too thoroughly. Needless to say, I didn't yet find anything...

Your solution to $(2)$   corresponds to $(a,b,c)=(1,3,1)$.

Comment: This response would be more appropriate as a [comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work)

Comment: @MaxCoplan Well, granted that it's not about Mathematica code, but it does provide (hopefully) an idea for a more efficient search. Apart from that, it may be a bit long for a comment anyway.